# Elasticsearch: query best match first

Tags: elasticsearch, search, text, full-text-search

I'm trying to figure out how to query articles from the database using a couple of words. And it should return a list of articles (best match first).

I have some articles like this:

```json
{
"article": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
 remaining essentially unchanged."
}
```

words to search: "standard", "industry", "printer", ...

so the response should be a list of articles that contains some of these words sorted by most matched.

In this case, what is the best approach to index and search it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to start indexing the field as type: "text" , and then run a match query against the field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

This will return all the documents based on TF-IDF which is:

- The most frequent the term is within a document the higher the score
- The most frequent the term is across all the data set the lower the score

Create the index:

```
PUT test_articles
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "article": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add some documents:

```
POST test_articles/_doc
{
"article": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's."
}
```

Querying:

```
GET test_articles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "article": "printing"
    }
  }
}
```

From here you can start adding more things like :

- Typo support
- Synonyms
- Stemming
  etc..

Welcome to Elasticsearch